# GAMLSS Random Effect Coefficients

Tags: mixed-model, gamlss

How do I extract the coefficients of my random effects in a [Gamlss](https://rdrr.io/cran/gamlss/man/random.html) model?

Let's take a simple example of a sample of individuals with intercepts which are normally distributed. Additional normally distributed error is added on top of this.

```
library(data.table)
library(nlme)
library(gamlss)

my.mean <- 4 # I wish to retrieve this value
my.sd <- 3 # I wish to retrieve this value
my.sd.id <- 2 # I wish to retrieve this value

set.seed(1234)
n <- 4 * 10^3
t <- 2

my.data <- CJ(id = seq(n), t = seq(t))
my.data[, mean_id := rnorm(1, my.mean, my.sd), by = id]
my.data[, value := mean_id + rnorm(t, 0, my.sd.id), by = id]

my.data[t == 1, sd(mean_id)] # 2.988226 which is ~my.sd
my.data[t == 1, sd(value)] # 3.57642 which is ~sqrt(my.sd^2 + my.sd.id^2)

l <- lme(
  fixed = value ~ 1,
  random = ~ 1|id,
  data = my.data
)
l
# Fixed(Intercept): 4.033439 (~my.mean)
# Random (Intercept): 2.974774 (~my.sd)
# Residual: 1.987995 (~my.sd.id)

m <- gamlss(
  formula = value ~ 1 + random(factor(id), df = NULL),
  sigma.formula = ~ 1,
  family = NO(),
  data = my.data
)
m
# Mu Coefficients (Intercept): 4.033 (~my.mean)
# Sigma Coefficients (Intercept): 0.4244 (exp(0.4244) = 1.528673 ??)
```

Although the *mu coefficient* from the Gamlss model corresponds to the expected value, I cannot find information about the random intercepts nor the residual error term.

The Gamlss *Sigma Coefficients (Intercept)* also seems to depend on the number of values (*t*) per id, which I think affects the internal optimising of *lambda* and the *df*. It converges to *log(my.sd.id)* for large *t*, whereas if I set *df = 1*, the value is approximately *sqrt(my.sd^2 + my.sd.id^2)*.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation:

> The function random() can be seen as a smoother for use with factors
> in gamlss(). It allows the fitted values for a factor predictor to be
> shrunk towards the overall mean, where the amount of shrinking depends
> either on lambda, or on the equivalent degrees of freedom or on the
> estimated sigma parameter (default).

If I understand it correctly, the equivalent of the *lme* method is one where GAMLSS does not shrink the parameters. We can force this by setting *df = 0* or *lambda = 10^9*. However, I could only find this argument in the *random()* notation of the random effect and not in the *re()* notation. Vice versa, I could only find the *VarCorr* for the *re()* method.

So one silly solution is to run the model twice:

```
m1 <- gamlss(
  formula = value ~ 1 + re(random = ~ 1|id),
  sigma.formula = ~ 1,
  family = NO(),
  data = my.data
)

m2 <- gamlss(
  formula = value ~ 1 + random(factor(id), df = 0),
  sigma.formula = ~ 1,
  family = NO(),
  data = my.data
)
```

Subsequently, the parameter estimates can be extracted from the combination of these two models.

```
my.mean.estimated <- m1$mu.coefficients[[1]] # ~4
my.sd.estimated <- as.numeric(VarCorr(getSmo(m1))[[3]]) # ~3
my.sd.id.estimated <- sqrt(exp(m2$sigma.coefficients[[1]])^2 - my.sd.estimated^2) # ~2
```